# How can I compile an Android APK from source?

Tags: apk

There are a couple of tutorials or even questions here about creating an application for Android. But I was wondering, if I just want to compile an application from the available source on Github, I'm not going to develop anything, do I need to install the Android SDK, Eclipse with ADT plugin, and the SDK tools and platforms?

In GNU/Linux you just have to install the build tools and dependency libraries, not an IDE, which is generally for doing the development. How would you proceed in compiling the APK? Not that I want it to be like GNU/Linux, but what are the required tools just for compiling? And do I need to downgrade my Java version to 6 when I'm compiling for Android 4.1.2 (if Java is needed)?

Also, there are no build instructions on the source, including a few steps on your answer would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The minimal requirements for building an Android app are usually the Android SDK and ant. Then, you are able to build the *majority*<sup>1</sup> of projects with the following steps.

- If there is no `build.xml` generate it

> android update project -p . -n $PROJECT_NAME -s

- Then build the project with

> `ant debug`

which will create an `.apk` signed with your debug key.

All other dependencies range from the used VCS (e.g. git), over the required 3rd party libraries, up to other required build tools (e.g. Android NDK).

<sup>1</sup> Why did I write *majority*? Because there is no definitive answer for such a question, as it simply depends on the used build system and the overall build setup of the project.

Let's have a look at [F-Droid's metadata,](https://gitorious.org/f-droid/fdroiddata/source/master%3ametadata) which is a big database of build recipes for FOSS Android apps. You will find that there are many ways how an Android app can be build. For example [`goo.TeaTimer`](https://gitorious.org/f-droid/fdroiddata/source/7f15c02a58513a02ddeb59f6a9ee3af64106ca24%3ametadata/goo.TeaTimer.txt) has a very clean and short build recipe, namely none, which defaults basically to F-Droid using `ant debug` to create the `.apk`. On the other hand, [`org.transdroid.full`](https://gitorious.org/f-droid/fdroiddata/source/7f15c02a58513a02ddeb59f6a9ee3af64106ca24%3ametadata/org.transdroid.full.txt) requires a few more steps to create the `.apk`: First the transdroid core library needs to be created, that is the `ant -f ../lib/build.xml` line in `prebuild`, then options are disabled with the `sed` command. Now the final `.apk` can be built.

Comment: Your command doesn't work because it lacks a `AndroidManifest.xml`, and the error from running is "Unable to load key from Google Drive, retrying: null"

Comment: The command was incorrect rendered. I've edited it. It's the same command F-Droid and I use within my Android project to generate `build.xml`. I've took a closer look at keepshare: It uses [sbt (simple build tool)](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) and is a good example for a project which does not use `ant` but instead some other build tool. Therefore the commands and tools to build the project differ.

Comment: The answer here only works for java apps; keepshare has Scala source code which is why SBT is necessary. There are very few Scala apps and F-Droid doesn't support it. Also ant is deprecated—gradle is the future for building Android apps. The app label in AndroidManifest.xml is Keepass database access so that's how it should appear in the launcher.

Comment: This statement is not correct. The used programming language and the used build system are not dependent on each other. SBT is not required to build Scala code, as little as Ant is required for Java code. The answer focuses on the most common build system for Android at this time: Ant. But it is true that the new build system is gradle. I think I made it clear in the answer, that there is no definitive answer for such a question, as it simply depends on the used build system and the overall build setup of the project.

Comment: Ant with the Android SDK build.xml only works with Java only apps; I think that's true.

Comment: No, you can transform anything with ant, not only Java. And Android's build.xml provides hooks to modify it to your needs (e.g. compile C code), it's also not restricted to Java.

Comment: I don't know why you'd use ant to compile C code for  an Android app. If ant could be used to compile Android Scala apps, I think it would have been done already.

Comment: C was just an example. It could be any language. And *why* one would do that doesn't matter for this discussion. But I'd would say that some developer do it because they don't want to depend on another build tool, for example.

Comment: Your answer still isn't relevant for Keepshare. The real answer is provided in comment #3.

Comment: That's right. I think more users benefit from an general answer compared to a specific one. OP already figured out that SBT is the used build tool.

Comment: It's a pity the OP still doesn't have a usable apk.